# How do I pass a function with arguments as an argument itself?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have a list of objects like this one:

```
friends = [
{'name': 'Sam', 'gender': 'male', 'sport': 'Basketball'},
{'name': 'Emily', 'gender': 'female', 'sport': 'volleyball'},
]
```

and I need to create functions "query", "select", and "field_filter" to work with these lists. All of it should look loke this:

```
»> result = query(
friends,
select('name', 'gender', 'sport'),
field_filter('sport', *('Basketball', 'volleyball')),
field_filter('gender', *('male',)),
)
»> result
[{'gender': 'male', 'name': 'Sam', 'sport': 'Basketball'}]
```

My idea was to make a query function which takes an array and ...functions as parameters and calls this functions with an array as *this* context. I managed to do this when i'm passing functions as is i.e. without arguments, but as you can see, it should be passed *with* parameters

For now my code looks like this:

```
let friends = [
  {'name': 'Sam', 'gender': 'male', 'sport': 'Basketball'},
  {'name': 'Emily', 'gender': 'female', 'sport': 'volleyball'},
]

const query = function(arr, ...funcs) {
  for (i of funcs) {
    i.call(arr)
  }
}

const select = function(...args) {
  console.log(this)
}

query(friends, select, select, select)
```

P.S. Initialy this task was for python but I wanted to make it on JS

Comment: the first argument to `function.call` is the `this` value for the function, which is why your call is failing ... you could either just do `i(arr)` or `i.call(null, arr)` or `i(...arr)` or `i.apply(null, arr)` - the latter two will call the function with the elements of friends as separate arguments - the first two will call the function with the array as the one and only argument

Comment: just noticed - you `console.log(this)` which should be outputting the array of friends, does it not do that for you?

Comment: @Bravo As you can see in example, functions must be called with argumets already and my idea was to pass an array as a context to avoid this. In my idea all the work would be made like `this.fliter`, `return this`, etc. Sorry if I didn't write it clearly enough

Comment: yes, what's the issue? you're calling the functions with the argument `arr` as the `this` value for the function ... you probably don't want to do this, and I've explained that

Comment: @Bravo Again, sorry if i'm being unclear here but the issue is when i'm calling query function like this: `query(friends, select('name'))` function runs immediatly with the wrong context and inside of query function all i get is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found perfectly working for this problem is closures: if function runs immideatly and performs body with wrong context - it should return a function which takes arguments and being called with proper context. Here's what I mean by that:

Edit: apparently it's not closures, but concept is the same - I return function which takes proper context

```
let friends = [
  {'name': 'Sam', 'gender': 'male', 'sport': 'Basketball'},
  {'name': 'Emily', 'gender': 'female', 'sport': 'volleyball'},
]

const query = function(arr, ...funcs) {
  for (i of funcs) {
    i.call(arr) // calls a function with proper context
  }
}

function select(...args) {
  return function() { // return a function which is being called inside query function
    // body of a function, e.g. console.log(this, args)
  }
}

let result = query(
  friends, 
  select('name', 'gender') // works perfectly
)
```

Feel free to point some mistakes/not good practices. After all, I'm not even a junior :)